# How can I convert QVariant to QString and vice versa in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I convert QVariant to QString and Vice versa?

Thanks

Answer (score 79, accepted):

From string:

```
QString qs;
QVariant qv(qs);
```

To string:

```
QString qs = qv.toString();
```

Tip: reading the [help](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toString) helps.

Comment: toString() does NOT return the value in the QVariant as a QString but rather describes the QVariant in a way that might be more suitable for debugging. I have found that QVariant::value<QString>() or QVariant::convert(QVariant::QString) seem to be more helpful, because they return the actual value in the QVariant.

Comment: @LennartRolland [the code example in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#value) explicitly states `value<QString>()` is the same as `toString()`. They both use `canConvert()` and `convert()` internally.

Comment: @hamstergene `toString()` appears to have begun working in qt 4.8; in qt 4.7, `value<QString>()` works, while `toString()` does not. So for this kind advice and compatibility, `value<QString>()` makes for a better general statement, unless qualified by version.

Comment: @hamstergene I thought the help is SO.

Comment: This does not work for certain types. For instance, when the QVariant contains a QStringList, .toString() returns a null string.