# Convert any QVariant to QString

Tags: c++, qt

I am aware of how to convert a `QVariant` containing a `QString` to a `QString`:
[How can I convert QVariant to QString and vice versa in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228826/how-can-i-convert-qvariant-to-qstring-and-vice-versa-in-qt)

What I want to ask is how do I convert ANY `QVariant` into a `QString`? i.e. even if my `QVariant` object has an `int`, is there an easy way to convert it to `QString`?

Comment: You can use the toString() method as long as it is one of those types: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toString otherwise, you can deduce if the type can be printed via http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#canConvert-1

Comment: What will you use that string for? does it have to be human-readable? if so, what if the `QVariant` contains say a `QPixmap`/`QImage`? How would you make a `QString` out of that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert QVariant to QString and vice versa in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228826/how-can-i-convert-qvariant-to-qstring-and-vice-versa-in-qt)

Comment: @FlorentUguet did you even read my first statement?

Comment: @manatttta I did, but what you ask is exactly the same. Even if your QVariant is an int, it'll be output as a String. Only if you use custom classes it won't work.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `QVariant::toString` for types listed in the method [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toString).

```
int value = 1;
QString s = QVariant(value).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Qstring formating

```
QVariant qv(1);
QString str = QString ("%1").arg(qv.toInt());
```

also you it could be more generic like this

```
if(qv.typeName() == QString("QString"))
   str = QString("%1").arg(qv.toString());
else if(qv.typeName() == QString("int"));
   str = QString ("%1").arg(qv.toInt());
...
```

or by using qv.type()

```
if(qv.type() == QVariant::String)
    str = QString("%1").arg(qv.toString());
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However that is specific for `int` types. I meant all types!

Comment: @manatttta i think you could write a function and iterate for all types, added an example.

Comment: @Falcon I would rather use type() than typeName(), like "if(qv.type() == QVariant::String) etc.

Comment: @e.jahandar , Never compare c strings using `==` use `strcmp` if you want to, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843640/2666212). In this case you can use `qv.type()` instead as suggested by @talamaki, this would be faster and more to the point. Please edit your answer

Comment: @Mike , its not c string, its Qstring with const char * , lookat documentation, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html the QString class has overloaded == operator

Comment: @e.jahandar , [`QVariant::typeName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#typeName) returns a `const char*` and you are comparing that with your string literal `"QString"` or `"int"`. Neither the LHS nor the RHS of the `operator==` is a `QString`.

Comment: It'd be less overhead to use `QString::number(foo)` instead of `QString("%1").arg(foo)`. And simply do `str = qv.toString()`. Finally, instead of `QString("xyz")` prefer `QStringLiteral("xyz")` - it saves on runtime conversions from C string to QString.